# How to serve images when using server side speaker notes?

Tags: reveal.js

I really like the server side speaker notes, but the node-based server doesn't serve my static images from the `img/` directory. As I can't use externally served images, is there a way to configure or extend reveal.js is there way to make it serve these images?

Answer (score 2):

If you place your images in `images/` instead of `img/` the speaker notes plugin will serve them.

Answer (score 0):

If you embed images via "data-background-image" use the url **`http://localhost:8000/img/yourpicture.jpg`**.